# Finding the code of the last inserted record in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, commit

I'm developing a system in C# and I must insert records in 2 tables and the tables are correlated. One table is called `Client` and has the columns `Cod_Cli`, `Nome_Cli`. The second table is `Phone` with columns `Cod_Phone`, `Num_Phone`. As a client may have several phone numbers, I created a correlation table, called `Cli_Phone`, with the columns `(Cod_Cli, Cod_Phone)`.

When I developed my C# program, I started a transaction so I can make a Commit (or a Rollback, if something goes wrong). After I insert the record in table `Phone`, I must get the code of this record to insert a new record in table `Cli_Phone`.

My problem is: how to get this code if I still didn’t commit the results? I don't want to use procedures.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: You don't need a lookup table for a one to many relationship.

Comment: You could use entity framework and DataContext. After adding record and submitting changes id is set automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In ADO.Net you can use OUTPUT in your insert query and ExecuteScalar for get id.

```
using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Your_table(column_1) output INSERTED.ID VALUES(@col1)",con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", "your_data");
        con.Open();

        int id =(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
            con.Close();

        return id;
    }
```

Comment: Although in this case it’s a 1:N relation, there are other tables that are related to table Phone. For example, table User (Cod_User, Name_User). There is also a table User_Phone, in the same way.
Oleg: I don’t know how to do this.
Chichiton: how do I use this? It was not clear for me.
Thanks to all.

Comment: Show your C# code which works with database. This will help answer in more detail.

Comment: I couldn't show my code. The site says it's too long. Do you have suggestions on how to send you the code?

Comment: Only the method in which the database is saved is needed. Try to remove unnecessary details. What framwork/technology are you use for db access?

Comment: I think in two parts it should go. But I had to remove much code

Comment: SqlCommand Cmd=new SqlCommand(TextoSQL, con, tran);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DddFone",SDdd);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Cmd.Dispose();
TextoSQL = "select MAX(COD) from TELEFONE";
Cmd = new SqlCommand(TextoSQL,con,tran);
SqlDataReader rdr;
rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: int CodFone=0;
if (rdr.Read())
{
CodFone = int.Parse(rdr.GetValue(0).ToString());
}
rdr.Close();
TextoSQL = "insert into CLIENTE_TELEFONE(CLIE_NA_CODIGO, TELE_NA_CODIGO) values (@CodCli, @CodFone)";
Cmd=new SqlCommand(TextoSQL, con, tran);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodCli", CodPri);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodFone", CodFone);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
tran.Commit();
return true;

Comment: When I use the "select MAX"... it doesn't bring me the correct number. I need to obtain the phone code BEFORE I commit.

Comment: When you insert phone in TELEFONE table, just save COD in variable and use it in your insert statmend to CLIENTE_TELEFONE table. It's look like code in my answer, but in instead INSERTED.id you need INSERTED.COD.

Comment: This collumn is identity.

Comment: But I think the command SELECT @@IDENTITY  worked. Right after the insert command and before the commit, I could get the code. Chichiton: thanks to you for your help.